# Add newsletter subscribe check option in order Thank you page Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I want to add option for customer to can subscribe to newsletter in the checkout Thank you page.

How I can remove the Submit button, and have there only a checkbox?

Thank you

Right now in my success page I add this code:

```
   <div class="order-newsletter">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
```

[image]

**Update:**

I found this code but in checkout success page I have this error:

***Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object***

```
<?php
$checked = true;
if($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) {
    if(!$this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()) {
        $checked = false;
    }
}   
 ?>
<li class="control">
<div class="input-box">
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($checked): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
</div>
<label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/52285/14174

You need to add your add box for newsletter and then hook observer for adding customer into subscription list.

Comment: thank you, you test this? will work on the success page?

Comment: The observer not adding customer into subscription list